# Expand visual selection to inner curly braces

Tags: visual-mode

Let's say I have this piece of code (cursor/selection is represented by `[]`):

```
[f]unction a()
{
    // ...
}
```

If I want to select the function declaration and the curly braces (and of course the content) I can do <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>%</kbd>, which select the first line, goes to the opening `{` and jump to the matching `}`.

Or I can do <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>{</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> which goes down to select around the `{}`, goes back to the start of the selection and move up to select the remaining line.

Now the question: why can't I do <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>?

I thought it could select the first line, then move down and expand around the curly braces.

Why is this not possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's trying to select the block that encompasses **all** of the selection. Since your selection is "leaking" out of the block and there's no other block containing it, it fails. Try `Vja{` on this to see what I mean:

```
{
   [f]unction a()
   {
       // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Nicely found, I thought the "inside"/"around" were for the cursor and not the position.